I have a wireshark packet from a program, is there any way to duplicate that packet in python?
I am trying to create a Python script to test whether a port is open or not without actually connecting to the device (the device is not another computer). I wiresharked the communication between my computer and the device and found a packet that requests data from the device. I would like to replicate that packet in my script so I can get a proper response from the device.
I initially tried writing a script that just executes a TCP connection on a port and sees whether the connection is accepted or not. I figured out when I do that the device just drops the existing connection on that port and connects to my computer, so my script always showed all ports were open, but they were not.

Scapy can read PCAP files, (optionally) manipulate and inject the packets.

[Edit] your question to show the script that doesn’t work. You can test for open ports without resorting to packet injection
